# Extract dyld_shared_cache on iOS7.1?

Tags: ios, frameworks, jailbreak, theos

I was trying to get the header files from the ToneKit framework on iOS7.1, but I found that I cannot use class-dump because there are no executable files inside the framework. From what I have found after some research, it seems as if the actual executable file is inside the dyld_shared_cache on the device. After reading [this](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Dyld_shared_cache)  article, it seems as if there are some tools to decrypt the cache, but since iOS 3, Apple has implemented ASLR which has made the decryption tools not work. How can I extract the Frameworks from inside the dyld_shared_cache on iOS7.1?

I am very new to jailbroken ios development so please bear with me.

Comment: Why not use header files from already extracted repositories such as https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/ToneKit.framework ?

Comment: Because I am interested in how they got these header files from these frameworks and I would like to dump the headers from my own device. :)

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/nst/RuntimeBrowser May give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in how they got those headers then the answer is very simple - iOS SDK. SDK contains ARM binaries of public and private frameworks because they are required to compile iOS applications. Class-dump them and you will get headers you need. `ToneKit.framework` binary is also in there.

Usually you don't need dyld_shared_cache, almost everything you need is either in iOS SDK or on a device itself like SpringBoard, other system applications etc.

Of course there are rare cases when dyld_shared_cache is the only place you can find certain binaries as they are missing from both iOS SDK and device. In that case I use [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_demo.shtml). It has free demo version that can open dyld_shared_cache files - you can even open individual binaries inside it rather than dump everything. You just need to copy dyld_shared_cache on your PC.

Answer (score 1):

I think Elias Limneos's [classdump-dyld](https://github.com/limneos/classdump-dyld) can help you. If not, check out [RuntimeBrowser](https://github.com/nst/RuntimeBrowser). Failing that, even, [weak-classdump](https://github.com/limneos/weak_classdump) has proven to be a very useful runtime tool for me.